# Richtextbox lines count

Tags: c#, winforms, count, richtextbox, lines

I'm developing a text editor in C#, and I'm trying to make a line count.

```
    private void updateNumberLabel()
    {
        Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
        int firstIndex = Document.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
        int firstLine = Document.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstIndex);

        pos.X = ClientRectangle.Width;
        pos.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;

        int lastIndex = Document.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
        int lastLine = Document.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

        int actualLine = Document.GetLineFromCharIndex(actualPos);
        pos = Document.GetPositionFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

        if (lastLine != actualLine)
        {
            numberLabel.Text = "";
            for (int i = firstLine; i <= lastLine + 1; i++)
            {
                numberLabel.Text += i + 1 + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine and adds the number of lines while you write them, but if you delete one, it will only update if you delete or add one more line.

I want make it instantaneous. If you delete one, the count shall be decreased instantaneously.

Comment: What's wrong with `richTextBox.Lines.Count()` ?

Comment: @DerApe , I assume he was asking for a line count like **ScintillaNET**, where it is displayed on the left hand side of the `RichTextBox`, or, can be displayed on the right hand side of the `RichTextBox` as well. In other words, there _shouldn't_ be anything "wrong" with `richTextBox.Lines.Count()` - I use this in multiple instances that require line counting, specifically involving `RichTextBox` -Although as a developer I tend to find **harder ways** to count lines, so that it looks "professional." ..Which probably sounds overzealous, but it makes my app look well-worked on. (At least to me.)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is too easy, but what about that:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var lineCount = richTextBox.Lines.Count();
  numberLabel.Text = lineCount.ToString();
}
```

Make sure you assign it to the `TextChanged` event.

If this is not what you need, please add some more information what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried:

numberLabel.Text += Document.Lines.Count().ToString() + "\n";

but it will add the lines to the label every time that the text changed

Comment: @Los799 You want to display the lines currently use right? So just do it like this: `numberLabel.Text = Document.Lines.Count().ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm really late, but Lines is an array of string. Just get the length.

```
richTexBox.Lines.Length.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found one open source and applied it to this problem.

I have confirmed that it works well and have implemented it.

[RichTextBox Colums and Row](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12197/Richer-RichTextBox-Part-2)

Simple Code(
The link has a demo source.):

```
this.rtb.CursorPositionChanged += 
    new System.EventHandler(this.rtb_CursorPositionChanged);
this.rtb.SelectionChanged += 
    new System.EventHandler(this.rtb_SelectionChanged);
.
.
.
private void rtb_CursorPositionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int line = rtb.CurrentLine;
    int col = rtb.CurrentColumn;
    int pos = rtb.CurrentPosition;

    statusBar.Text = "Line " + line + ", Col " + col + 
                     ", Position " + pos;
}

private void rtb_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int start = rtb.SelectionStart;
    int end = rtb.SelectionEnd;
    int length = rtb.SelectionLength;

    statusBar.Text = "Start " + start + ", End " + end + 
                     ", Length " + length;
}
```

```
namespace Nik.UserControls
{
    public class RicherTextBox2 : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    {
        public event EventHandler CursorPositionChanged;

        protected virtual void OnCursorPositionChanged( EventArgs e )
        {
            if ( CursorPositionChanged != null )
                CursorPositionChanged( this, e );
        }

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged( EventArgs e )
        {
            if ( SelectionLength == 0 )
                OnCursorPositionChanged( e );
            else
                base.OnSelectionChanged( e );
        }

        public int CurrentColumn
        {
            get { return CursorPosition.Column( this, SelectionStart ); }
        }

        public int CurrentLine
        {
            get { return CursorPosition.Line( this, SelectionStart ); }
        }

        public int CurrentPosition
        {
            get { return this.SelectionStart; }
        }

        public int SelectionEnd
        {
            get { return SelectionStart + SelectionLength; }
        }
    }

    internal class CursorPosition
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")] 
        public static extern int GetCaretPos(ref Point lpPoint);

        private static int GetCorrection(RichTextBox e, int index)
        {
            Point pt1 = Point.Empty;
            GetCaretPos(ref pt1);
            Point pt2 = e.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);

            if ( pt1 != pt2 )
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        public static int Line( RichTextBox e, int index )
        {
             int correction = GetCorrection( e, index );
             return e.GetLineFromCharIndex( index ) - correction + 1;
        }

        public static int Column( RichTextBox e, int index1 )
        {
             int correction = GetCorrection( e, index1 );
             Point p = e.GetPositionFromCharIndex( index1 - correction );

             if ( p.X == 1 )
                 return 1;

             p.X = 0;
             int index2 = e.GetCharIndexFromPosition( p );

             int col = index1 - index2 + 1;

             return col;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los799

Sorry for answering a "bit" late, I saw this question just now.
But if the problem still stands, here's a simple way to count lines, just use a foreach loop:

```
int CountOfLines = 1;//1 because min 1 line is always in a text of a control, that has a Text property
foreach (char c in YourText)
            {
                if (c == '\r' | c == '\n')//these are all equal the ENTER key
                {
                    CountOfLines++;
                }
            }
```

You can also use foreach to count characters as well, but with foreach you can choose characters, that you don't want to be counted in the count of characters. For example:

```
int CountOfCharacters = 0;//0 because by default there are no characters in a textbox or label.
foreach (char c in YourText)
            {
                if (c != '\t' & c != '\n' & c != '\r')//in this example I want to count only the characters that are not an ENTER or a TAB.
                {
                    CountOfCharacters++;
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps you and everybody else, who's reading this, even if it's a bit late answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to battle with the default rich text box, why don't you try making your own control so you have full control of the text formatting?

After all, if you're developing your own text editor, it would make sense to have text stored and managed in a way that makes sense to you, the developer, instead of trying to fight with a format designed for a slightly different purpose.

Comment: I'm newbie on C#, if I don't know how to count lines, how could I make my own control? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I'm doing something I very rarely do and saying try Romano's Environment.NewLine solution instead. Note line begins with a capital L.

Answer (score -1):

Newer solution to this question for WPF applications
DOK1 is a WPF flow document
TX1 is a TextBox control
TX1.Text = DOK1.Blocks.Count.ToString();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please translate your post to English. Most of us don't speak your language.