# How To Get The Line Count Of A RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Is there a simple way to simulate `TextBox.LineCount` for a `RichTextBox`? I've been looking at other posts and solutions but they're extremely outdated.

Other Posts:

[Richtextbox lines count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520642/richtextbox-lines-count)

[How many Lines in RichTextBox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12c71bb7-c7d3-452a-91dd-a625ab412935/how-many-lines-in-richtextbox?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text from the control and split it to an array with `Environment.NewLine` separator then you can check the length of the array to get the line count.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextRange MyText = new TextRange(
    richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart,
    richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd
     );

    string[] splittedLines = MyText.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }
                                  , StringSplitOptions.None); // or StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries

    MessageBox.Show(splittedLines.Length.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It looks good except I need the empty lines too. I want to capture all the lines with and without content. How would I do that?

Comment: Without the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, it takes the `RichTextBox` Text - for example like "\r\n" - and turns it into two items, which the length of that is 2 and incorrect, it should be 1.

Comment: I just changed the `StringSplitOptions` you suggested to `StringSplitOptions.None` and handled the result on my own, thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding correctly, you want line count including cases in which multiple lines are rendered because of word wrapping. If that's the case, you'll need to count the frequency of a newline in the text of the richtextbox plus factor in the width of the richtextbox to detect wordwrap.

Comment: I have word wrapping off on my `RichTextBox`, and I've thought about counting the newline character in the string representation of the content within the `RichTextBox`, but RichTextBox's have this weird behavior where it automatically generates a "\r\n" when I specifically wanted to insert an empty string. I'm still new to using RichTextBox's but that's what I observed.

Comment: My post above was focused on what MSDN says about the behavior of TextBox.LineCount since you're looking to replicate that. The weird behavior in your comment above, is that indicating you want zero when the RichTextBox is empty but you still want to count empty lines when they're part of text that includes more than just that line that's empty?

Comment: Yes, let's say my `RichTextBox` is empty and it has focus, I want that first line to be considered as a line represented by an empty string, so in that case the LineCount will be 1.